# CloudFormation Rollback on Template? When changing default region in template

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation

I have been using the current template at this link:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-a-cross-regioncross-account-code-deployment-solution-on-aws/

By default it only allows you to deploy to US-EAST-1, US-WEST-2 and EU-WEST-1. Part of my requirements are that I need to have Testing in US-EAST-1, Pre-Production US-EAST-2 and production in EU-WEST-1.

When I change the mapping of the template to add a new region I get the following error.

testing-nv
The following resource(s) failed to create: [WaitCondition]. . Rollback requested by user.

WaitCondition timed out. Received 0 conditions when expecting 1

I expected the Pipeline to run through and then Copy the test file to a source S3 bucket in the source region. I believe this error is due to the small changes I made to the default templates but how I am able to change the regions per my requirements.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the stack to not delete on failure. Then go into the EC2 instances it creates and check their logs under `/var/log/cfm-init*` and `/var/log/cloud*`. There should be an error there that prevents the instance from signalling it's ready. Without the signal, you get the timeout. Either that or the process is slower for some reason and you need to increase the timeout of 900 seconds in line 461.